# Unable to set Orientation Property of the Pivot Field Class

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to drop a column "CalendarWeekBegin" into the Rows of a Pivot Table.

```
 PivotTableName="NewPivotTable3"
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName).PivotFields("CalendarWeekBegin")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
```

This code works fine for few tables but for one big table, it's throwing

```
 Error 1004:Unable to set Orientation Property of the Pivot Field Class
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried to manually insert the CalendarWeekBegin field into "rows" of pivot table but I get this error:

```
A Pivot Table report cannot overlap a table or XML Mapping
```